# Why aren't the angular EventEmitter subscribe method parameters strongly typed?

Tags: angular

Why aren't the angular EventEmitter subscribe method parameters strongly typed?

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a14dc2d7a4821a19f20a9547053a5734798f541e/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L102

```
subscribe(generatorOrNext?: any, error?: any, complete?: any): Subscription {
  ...
}
```

instead of something like

```
subscribe(generator: DefForGenerator): Subscription;
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
subscribe(generatorOrNext?: any, error?: any, complete?: any): Subscription {
  ...
}
```

Comment: it is strongly typed? all of angular/typescript is

Comment: it is not because of `any`

Comment: thats the subscription, not the event emitter

Comment: You can track a related issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29016. This isn't really an SO question, only the relevant developers can tell you why they chose that.

Comment: that is the subscribe method of the EventEmitter

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jonrsharpe 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616558/why-arent-the-angular-eventemitter-subscribe-method-parameters-strongly-typed#comment97926643_55616558) sends you in the right direction.

According to this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6934#issuecomment-180909957) you shouldn't be using `EventEmitter.subscribe()` / its only designed to be consumed by the `@Output()` metadata. So the `any` typing may be the developers discouraging the use of the method.